# How to implement "And"-Condition in ydn db?

Tags: ydn-db

I need help in ydn db.
My issue is as follows: How can I fetch records by 2 conditions?
In sql it would be:

```
"SELECT * FROM store WHERE name='Test' AND cool=1;"
```

Currently my attempt looks like this:

```
var keyRange = ydn.db.KeyRange.bound(['Test', true]);

var db = DB.getDatabase();

database
.get('personStore', 'name, cool', keyRange)
.done(function(records) {
    console.log(records);
});
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in [this page](http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/nosql-query.html), you can use compound index (as you did) or key joining. If you index `['name', 'cool']`, you should be able to query by `ydn.db.KeyRange.only(['Test', 1])`. Note that boolean is not a valid key. Even if `cool` is boolean value, you have to index as integer value. But my suggestion is index only `name` and, just query name and filter out `cool` value on the result set.

Comment: What's most helpful here to me in this post is that booleans can't be used as index keys. I'd suggest updating the documentation to make that more clear, if possible. :)